# Why does the scrollbox not show the scroll in unreal engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-umg

[image]

Above is the screenshot of the scrollbox that I'm trying to create but it won't show the scroll on the side. You can see that the contents are overflowing out of the scrollbox but it still won't show or do the scroll. Can anyone please figure out the issue and tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm stuck at this.

Comment: The most obvious thing would be if your Scroll Box's Scroll > Scroll Bar Visibility parameter was not set to Visible. If that isn't it, perhaps you can past more screenshots of the other Detail sections of the Scroll Box (especially the Scroll section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I have found the solution on my own. It seems like I have been adding and resizing my buttons the wrong way. I was adjusting the "scale" whereas you should be adjusting the image size.